# Python package :MLE for Dirichlet distribution

Tags: python, statistics, mle, dirichlet

I was wondering if someone knew about a python package that implements MLE to estimate parameters of a Dirichlet distribution.

Answer (score 8):

Eric Suh has a package [here](https://github.com/ericsuh/dirichlet).

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/ericsuh/dirichlet.git
```

Then:

```
import numpy
import dirichlet
a0 = numpy.array([100, 299, 100])
D0 = numpy.random.dirichlet(a0, 1000)
dirichlet.mle(D0)
```